# How to make sublime saving files without asking for permissions?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am using `Sublime Text 2` on my Mac (10.9)

It's quite weird that for over 3 months, it works fine. Today it suddenly prompts me to enter the administrator's password to save a file.

I installed [this](https://sublime.wbond.net/) very popular plugin today. But I don't know why this is connected.

It's quite annoying to enter admin's password every time I save a file (actually not every time but quite often)

Is there anything I need to check?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the folder/files you are working on?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Oh, those files are created with vim. I think I know what's happening there. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured out that those files were created by `vim` when I am using my Mac as `root`. So with a `chown myusername filename` the problem solved.

Anyway I am not sure whether this is 100% reliable because I did not retry it for many times.

Answer (score 10):

You can use

```
sudo chown -R myuser folder/*
```

to change the permission recursively in the application

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo chown username -R .
```

this changes file permission of current directory recursively

Answer (score 1):

starting sublime with sudo worked for me 
like:

```
sudo /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text
```

Comment: you can start `sublime` with following command `sudo subl` so do not need to enter path everytime

Answer (score 1):

Launch the sublime using the following simple command. Once you launched, it won't ask password for each time you save.

```
sudo subl
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use,

`sudo chown $USER -R .`

To change current user permissions.